# xpath with dom document

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xpath, document.evaluate

I'm trying the find a xml node with xpath query. but i cannot make it working. In firefox result is always "undefined" and chrome throws a error code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var xmlString = '<form><name>test</name></form>';
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');

var result = doc.evaluate('/form/name', doc, 
                          null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

alert(result.stringValue);

</script>
```

what's wrong with this code ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know why did you get this error, but you can change `XPathResult.ANY_TYPE` to `XPathResult.STRING_TYPE` and will works (tested in firefox 3.6).

See:

```
var xmlString = '<form><name>test</name></form>';
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');
var result = doc.evaluate('/form/name', doc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);
alert(result.stringValue); // returns 'test'
```

See in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seYQH/).

---

**DETAILS:**

The 4th parameter of method `evaluate` is a integer where you specify what kind of result do you need ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate)). There are many [types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate#Result_types), as integer, string and any type. This method returns a [XPathResult](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDOMXPathResult), that has many properties.

You must match the property (numberValue, stringValue) with the property used in evaluate.

I just don't understand why `any type` didn't work with `string value`.

Answer (score 3):

`XPathResult.ANY_TYPE` would return a node set for xpath expression `/form/name`, so `result.stringValue` would have trouble converting node set to string. In this case you could use `result.iterateNext().textContent`

However, an expression like `count(/form/name)` would return a number value when used with `XPathResult.ANY_TYPE` and you could use `result.numberValue` to retrieve the number in that case.

Some more detailed explanation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate#Result_types